# Creating a VPN Tunnel between website and the server

Tags: vpn, website, tunneling

The machine which is connected in server LAN has the IP Camera Connected. From server the IP camera video feed can be viewable. I would like to view this IP camera from anywhere on the world through internet. So on the webpage i can embed any player like vlc to view.

But the problem is the IP camera doesnt have the static IP address.

So i guess using VPN connection if the website or web browser which i browsing the server page belongs to the server LAN then i can able to view the IP camera.

Am i clear ? Let me know the solutions or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you do in this situation is:

1. Sign up for a dyndns account, such taht webrsk.mine.nu goes to your dynamic IP for the camera.
2. Setup the router to port forward port 8080 to the camera.

Now you add a link from your website to

> http://webrsk.mine.nu:8080

Which will connect to your dynamic/home/lan camera.

This page http://www.handymanhowto.com/2009/07/25/how-to-install-a-panasonic-network-camera-part-3/ walks through the configuration for a Panasonic webcam, which if you don't have a Panasonic you can ignore that specific part, and use it as a general guide for setting up port forwarding and dyndns.

Be sure to enable **security** on your camera (username/password) such that random strangers can't view your camera!

Comment: if the camera is behind a router, you'll want to give it a static IP and a port forward from the router. in addition to the dyndns

Comment: You may also want to address the problem of not making the camera accessible to everyone else on the Internet - have a look at http://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=en&rls=en&q=inurl:view.shtml&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 and you'll see what I mean.